# What elements would be created by bombarding quark matter with neutrons?

Tags: quarks, exotic-matter

Assuming we managed to find or create either Strange Quark Matter or UpDown Quark Matter, I've read the suggestion that it would be stable, but that bombarding it with neutrons would cause it to break up and give off energy. What elements would likely be created out of the breakup?

Comment: I don't think we have good enough QCD models to predict that (after all, we can't even predict the stability of quark matter well). One might make an analogy to neutron star mergers and think that there would be a lot of r-process elements, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Even predicting what will happen when a "normal" nucleus is bombarded by neutrons can be tricky - hence the need for experiment.  In general there may be multiple possible outcomes.